# Is there a major car rental company in the U.S. that also rents roof top cargo box?

Tags: usa, car-rentals

I'm looking for a major car rental company that also rent roof top cargo box.  Anyone know of any company that offer this service?

Comment: I imagine U-Haul and all the major moving companies do.

Comment: http://www.uhaul.com/MovingSupplies/Wheelchair-Cargo/Cargo-carriers/Roof-Top-Cargo-Carrier?id=213

Comment: hmmm...Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that's purchasing the cargo carrier, not renting.

Comment: @ChairmanMeow: for US$40, who cares?  Do you think you'd really save money by renting one?

Comment: that's not the point, my question asks for major car renal company that also rents cargo box.

Comment: I understand that's your question. But presumably you're asking the question because you have a problem to solve. And if the problem can be solved as well or better by buying a cargo carrier, one might expect you to appreciate that information. But maybe I'm being silly.

Comment: thanks, i don't want to buy one, what's why i'm asking if there's a car rental company that also rents cargo box.

Comment: But *why* don't you want to buy one?  To save money? If you can buy one cheaper than renting, it won't save money. THAT is the point.

Comment: i want to rent a car and it would be preferable if that company also provide cargo box rental service.

Comment: You're not answering my question. I suppose you're more interested in arguing than getting an answer.  I'm off to do better things.

Comment: "Hey Chairman Meow, why can't you just make your own cargo box, you save money and gain experience." - Flimzy

Comment: Thanks Flimzy for that suggestion, but I would like to know if there are rental companies that also rents cargo boxes

Comment: If you buy one you need to get rid of it after.  That is inconvenient.  Also, if the rental company provides it, it all comes from one place, you don't need to go to a separate store after, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience when rental car companies rent you anything that you might want to add to a car (extended roofrack, car seat, etc) the price per day is a large fraction of the total price of the item. For example $20/day for something that costs $35. I suppose this is to cover all the paperwork and hassle of making sure you return the item with the car, storing the item somewhere when nobody is renting it, and dealing with potential liability around the way the item is attached to the car.

As a result your best bet is to buy the item outright, and either resell it, give it to a charity, or leave it at the side of the road for someone to just take when you're done. It can be argued that it's inconvenient to drive your just-rented car to some kind of store to get the accessory before carrying on with whatever you're renting the car for, and I'm not going to argue with that, but unless you're renting for just one or two days, the extra cost is going to wildly outweigh that inconvenience.

Without more details (the length of your trip, the reason you want the box, the constraints that make it very difficult to get the box anywhere other than the car rental company) you're unlikely to get a better answer than this: drive your rental car to a store that sells roof top cargo boxes, and buy the cheapest you can.

Comment: Or rent a bigger car?

Comment: I'll second this. Per day, the cost to rent a child's car seat as an extra is typically more than the cost to rent a car.

Comment: @pnuts want to elaborate why, so Kate can improve her answer?

Comment: @Kate - hopefully you can expand on this old answer?